# icCube ETL - cached table - beyond 100 rows

Tags: etl, iccube

I am using the cached table functionality as described [in the online documentation](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/etl_javascript2.php) to setup an array to support financial consolidation (to be more precise: intercompany elimination).

Prototyped on a small data set, the ETL code works seemingless, but when I start using a source table that has more than 100 rows (approx. 1400 to be precise), I only get the maximum 100 rows.

What do I need to do to cache the complete table?

My Initialization Code looks as follows:

```
var df = table("costcenter structure");
var n = df.count();
debug ("************************** count: " + n);
```

BTW: I use the same table "costcenter structure" to create the parent-child hiearchy and that is working fine.

Comment: Don't use the 'browse' that is only getting 100 rows from all tables , but use the  Read View feature.

Comment: Thanks. That I missed that! In the preview, you only get the first 100 rows, I was not aware that this applied to the cached tables as well. 

Now when I export the result from the dataview or load the code, all data is processed.

Solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'browse' data is getting the first 100 rows from all tables, included the ones cached.

You've to simulate a full load by using for example the 'Read View' or 'Export' button.